# What is the UK equivalent of 'murica and 'straya?

Tags: terminology, american-english, british-english, slang, australian-english

There is a pejorative phrase in the United States for country hicks that has recently arisen:

> 'murica

Implying that that user of the phrase doesn't pronounce their words properly and doesn't care.

Specifically it denotes people who are carefree about their appearance and behaviour, who don't live in the coastal states and are unworried about needing to come across as intelligent.

In Australia - the equivalent phrase is:

> 'straya

My question is: **What is the UK equivalent of '[murica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27Murica) and '[straya](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Straya)?**

Comment: The linked articles give different definitions of " 'Murica" and " 'Straya", not the ones you suggest. Have you any supporting evidence (not just anecdotal) for the broadened usages you claim? 'People who say " 'Murica" ' or 'He's one of those people who say " 'Murica" ' I wouldn't query. But you seem to suggest "He's a 'Murica/n' " being used as a pejorative, as opposed to by one who normally speaks that way.

Comment: Is this disregard for category (country vs. resident) a requirement?

Comment: Does anyone outside the South say 'Murca?

Comment: @hawkeye - can you provide example sentences using the two words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest **[Ingerland](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ingerland)**, possibly also spelt **In-ger-land**:

> *informal* a jocular spelling of England, as pronounced in the chants of sports, esp football, supporters

<sup>collins</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The term **oik** may well fit:

[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oik):

> *oik* (ɔɪk) n [derogatory slang] Brit
>
> a person regarded as inferior because ignorant, ill-educated, or
>   lower-class

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oik) suggests a parallel etymology:

> Etymology
>
> Unknown, early 20th century. Possibly onomatopoeic, in imitation of
>   uncultivated speech.

Comment: Most terms have.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - *oik* half-works: the (patronising) sense of ignorant/ill-educated/lower class  suggested by the OP for '*murica*' and '*'straya'*.  But it doesn't include the (semi-disguised) put down of crude patriotism that is also implied.  Curiously hard to locate an equivalent for 'British' or 'English'.

Comment: You need to specify this in your question (and to respond to the requests for clarification). I can't think of a corresponding pejorative BrE term based on a dialect form of 'England', 'Britain' etc.

Comment: [@EdwinAshworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/435893/what-is-the-uk-equivalent-of-murica-and-straya#comment1048386_435895) Of course not ... it wouldn't be proper. :)

Comment: @JJJ None of those is a ' a pejorative phrase in the United Kingdom for country hicks'.

Comment: I'm saying that the expressions listed there are not used in the UK to describe Brits regarded as inferior because they are seen to be ignorant, ill-educated, or lower-class. 'Oiks' is (but can provoke anger).

Comment: @JJJ 'Implying that that user of the phrase doesn't pronounce their words properly and doesn't care'?